# 6788 patch - page not found error in admin

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-6788

After installing the 6788 patch,I get page not found error in admin custom module.my adminhtml.xml likes this

```
    <config>
    <menu>
        <sales>
            <children>
                <camshiprestriction translate="title" module="camshiprestriction">
                    <title>Ship Restrictions</title>
                    <sort_order>700</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/camshiprestriction_rule</action>
                </camshiprestriction>
            </children>
        </sales>
    </menu>
```

config.xml file

```
          <admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <camshiprestriction before="Mage_Adminhtml">Ami_Shiprestriction_Adminhtml</camshiprestriction>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin> 

<adminhtml>
    <menu>
        <sales>
            <children>
                <camshiprestriction translate="title" module="camshiprestriction">
                    <title>Shipping Restrictions</title>
                    <sort_order>700</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/camshiprestriction_rule</action>
                </camshiprestriction>
            </children>
        </sales>
    </menu>
```

how to solve it

Comment: Please add config file content for camshiprestriction module to your question

Comment: i updated with config.xml @JaiminSutariya

Comment: Please also show the controller, there's probably something wrong with the `_isAllowed()` method

Comment: Did you get the issue resolved?

Comment: yes i changed url in grid.php file @JaiminSutariya

Comment: Please add your solution as answer so it will help others facing similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In block grid.php , i changed url code

Before

```
        $this->addColumn('action',array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Action'), 
        'width'     => '50px',
        'type'      => 'action',
        'actions'   => array(
            array(
                'caption' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Duplicate'),
                'url'     => array('base' => 'amshiprestriction/adminhtml_rule/duplicate'),
                'field'   => 'rule_id'
            )
        ),
```

After

```
     $this->addColumn('action',array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Action'), 
        'width'     => '50px',
        'type'      => 'action',
        'actions'   => array(
            array(
                'caption' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Duplicate'),
                /* I changed here */
                'url'     => array('base' => 'adminhtml/camshiprestriction_rule/duplicate'),
                'field'   => 'rule_id'
            )
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with your menu code,
Please try below code.

```
<menu>
    <sales>
        <children>
            <camshiprestriction translate="title" module="camshiprestriction">
                <title>Shipping Restrictions</title>
                <sort_order>700</sort_order>
                <action>camshiprestriction/adminhtml_camshiprestriction/rule</action>
            </camshiprestriction>
        </children>
    </sales>
</menu>
```